Page.tsx file being Greyed Out in Next.js 14 App Router
I have a Next.js 14 project with over 10 routes, all of which are working fine. However, when I try to add any new route with a page.tsx file, it appears greyed out, and I am unable to commit it. This issue is not related to .gitignore as other new files created are working fine. The problem seems specific to the page.tsx file. Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to resolve it? Or maybe is there any restriction to how many page.tsx files can be created.
I have attached the screenshot below to show only newly created files i.e feature-in-beta are greyed out.  Any help will be appreciated.

